# Regex attribute out of tag

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to regex src attribute (without its content/value) only and replace it with something else.

It has to verify the HTML tag also (img in the example).

Test data example:

```
<img src="http://example.com" class="something" />
```

Now I need to get only "src" and replace it. Is it possible to get it as first/only match with lookbehind/lookahead in PHP?

Comment: Don't use regexes on html. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
preg_replace('/(<img[^>]*src=")[^"]*"/', '$1'.$new.'"', $html)
```

lookbehind isn't possible, because it can't be of variable length.

Comment: Indeed, you can't use a lookbehind (cause of variable length), but you can use the `\K` feature that remove all the match before it from the match result, ex:`<img\b[^>]*src="\K[^"]*(?=")` then your replacement string is only: `$new`

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression shouldn't be used to parse html.
Instead, modify the DOM to do what you need.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<img src="http://example.com" class="something" />');
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $image->setAttribute('src','http://www.google.com');
    echo htmlentities($doc->saveHTML($image));
}
```